# USB modems with hub on Linux unstable network

Tags: linux, usb, power-supply, usb-hub

I need help to understand what is happening when coupling USB hub with USB modems.
I bought two USB 2.0 powered hub with 10 ports each. The first one has 12V 2,5A. The second one deliver 12V5A.
I have 7 USB modems that are supposed to use 5V/500ma each.
I've got two computers: a debian with only USB 2.0 ports, and an archlinux with some 3.0 and 2.0 ports.

Here are all my observations:

- each USB modem plugged independently in any hub or in any computer have a stable network.
- if I plug 7 modems, on the first hub only 5 devices can work with a stable network, on the second hub 6 are stable, whatever the computer
- if I split the modems over 2 hubs, in USB 3.0 ports of my archlinux they all have a stable network (5 in one and 2 in another)
- if I do the same splitting in my debian, only 6 devices are stable.

I don't understand the logic behind at all.

I want to highlight that there are always enough power to communicate with the modems using AT commands, but the network is unstable.

What do you think is the issue? I thought I had not enough power but it seems that new hub should be more than enough. Is there some other limit in Linux? Or in the hardware those computers?

Answer (score 0):

The mathematics of it : Each modem takes 0.5A. So 5 of them
take 2.5A which exhausts the 2.5A hub, but not the 5A one.

The 5A-rated hub can only support 6 modems, which should make 3A,
but not 7 modems that make 3.5A. For me this means that it's really
a 3A hub, not 5A.

To this should be added the differences between the USB ports.
USB 2.0 has a maximum speed of 480 Mbps while USB 3.0 can do 1000 Mbps.
Therefore the computer with only USB 2.0 ports can support less network
traffic.

That said, hardware can never be counted upon to perform at its rated
speed and power requirements. Some difference between real and rated
performance should be expected, and may increase with the age of the device,

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I agree with the math for the first hub. For the second one, I'm not sure it's advertised as 5A delivering 600ma per port.       About the network traffic, I only read SMS through the modem. I don't think there's too much traffic. Its rather the network between the modem and the  isp that is instable, not between the modem and the computer.